# N:M eager loading (include) using sequelizejs

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

So I found myself into troubles trying to use the include eager loading feature in M:N relations

The user model relation:

```
User.belongsToMany(models.rol, {
      through: {
        model: models['usuario_rol']
      },
      as: {
        plural: 'roles',
        singular: 'rol'
      },
      foreignKey: 'idusuario'
});
```

The rol model relation:

```
Rol.belongsToMany(models.usuario, {
      through: {
        model: models['usuario_rol']
      },
      foreignKey: 'idrol'
});
```

Finally the query:

```
db.usuario.findOne({
    where: {
      id: insert.id
    },
    include: [
      {
        model: db.rol
      }
    ]
});
```

If we try this the it crashes with Error: rol is not associated to usuario!

The curious is that with an instance of the sequelize user object I can fetch the roles using user.getRoles()

Do you have any idea of why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you specify an alias in the association function (in this case `roles`) you have to pass that to the include as well:

```
return User.findOne({
  where: {
    id: 52
  },
  include: [
    {
      model: rol,
      as: 'roles'
    }
  ]
});
```

You can also save the association and pass that instead:

```
User.Roles = User.belongsToMany(models.rol, {
  through: {
    model: models['usuario_rol']
  },
  as: {
    plural: 'roles',
    singular: 'rol'
  },
  foreignKey: 'idusuario'
});

return User.findOne({
  where: {
    id: 52
  },
  include: [
    {
      association: User.Roles
    }
  ]
});
```